# Json method is not recognized in Web Api controller

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an web api controller

```
using sport.BLL.Abstract;
using sport.BLL.Concrete;
using sport.DAL.Entities;
using sport.webApi.Models;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;  
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;

namespace sport.webApi.Controllers 
{
    public class AccountManageController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = item.Username, Email = item.Email };
            var result = UserManager.CreateAsync(user, item.Password);
            if (result.Result.Succeeded)
            {

                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(item.Username);
                var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, item.Role);
                ajt_collaborator entity = Mapper.Map<CollaborateurModel, ajt_collaborator>(item);
                entity.id_user_fk = currentUser.Id;
                entity.is_deleted = false; 
                repo.CreateCollaborator(entity); 
                var response = new { Success = true }; 
                return  Json(response);


            }
            else
            {
                var errorResponse = new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "error" };
                return  Json(errorResponse);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I got an error in this line :

**return  Json(response);**

the Json Method is not recognized!!! when I googled about that I get this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which indicates that `Json` method is included in `System.Web.Mvc`. Even I try to import this namespace I get the same error?

1. So is the reason of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you returning Json in a `ActionResult` method? It is not the answer to a question. However, it is an important issue.

Comment: Api controllers aren't meant to return `ActionResult`. You're mixing regular controllers with Api controllers.

Comment: As I guess, the problem is that you are inheriting from `ApiController` and `Json` is a member of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. Try using `return new JsonResult { data = response };`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev It is a good idea but I don't need to send data but only the status ( success ou failure) . I need some thing like `return new JsonResult{sucess =false}`

Comment: @LamloumiAfif `return new JsonResult { data = true };` works fine.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it's works for me thanks, plz post it as an answer. It is the easier solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are inheriting from `ApiController` but `Json` is a member of `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

Try using `JsonResult`:

```
return new JsonResult { data = yourData; }
```

You can set any object to a data as it will be serialized to a JSON.

For instance, if you need to return only a result of operation, you can use it   this way:

```
return new JsonResult { data = true; } // or false
```

However, it is a good practice to describe a result class and return objects.

Comment: According to the below link, ApiController **does** offer a Json() method.  But according to my dev environment, it doesn't...  Which is why I'm here!  Is this documentation just nonsense?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json``1(``0)

Answer (score 6):

> How can I fix it?

The reason is in the fact that you aren't inheriting from `Controller` but from `ApiController`, where the former has [`Json(object o)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as a method in it's base class, but that doesn't actually matter, as there is a fundamental problem with your approach.

`ApiController` which is used with WebAPI isn't meant to return an `ActionResult`, which is a concept that belongs to MVC. Instead, you simply return your POCO and let the WebAPI framework handle serialization for you:

```
public object CreateAccount(CollaborateurModel item)
{
    // Do stuff:
    if (result.Result.Succeeded)
    {
        return new { Success = true }
    }
    else
    {
        return new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "error" };   
    }                               
}
```

You can set your [formatter configuration](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) in your `Global.asax.cs` file, and tell it exactly which ones to use (in your case, you'll want the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`).

Comment: I get in this line `return result.Result.Succeeded ? new { Success = true } : 
                                     new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "error" };` this error **Type of conditional expression cannot be determinated because there is no implicit conversion**

Comment: @LamloumiAfif You're right, I tested this with the wrong anon type creation. Fixed the code.

Comment: Change it to `if-else`. The ternary operator `?:` requires both objects to be of the same type. In ypour case they're not. It's been corrected in the answer.

Comment: @JotaBe Yeah that's what I did. Thanks :)