# Json() method is documented for Web API but present only in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I cannot find the `Json()` method in `System.Web.Http.ApiController`, though the method is present in `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

I have checked post [Json method is not recognized in Web Api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726242/json-method-is-not-recognized-in-web-api-controller). I can see the same from the class definitions of `Controller` & `ApiController`.

BUT, in [ApiController.Json Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.json(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Json%60%601(%60%600)) MSDN documentation (no version mentioned), it says `Json()` is part of Api Controller/Web API.

What am I missing here? Why the `Json()` method is not present in `ApiController` as stated in the official docs! (I know, ApiController can still return JSON data when asked for.)

My `System.Web.Http` version is `4.0.0.0`

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyServices.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public object Get()
        {
            return Json("Dummy"); //<= doesn't compile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the controller or at least the single WebAPI method with with the usings etc?

Comment: @Coulton Added code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed an older version of the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package (4.0.20505.0) in order to get the v4.0.0.0 version of the assembly. I then looked at the assembly with JustDecompile. `ApiController` does *not* have a `Json` method in that version. However in v5.2.3 of that package it does. The documentation you're referencing is for the newer version.

**ApiController v4.0.0.0**

[image: ApiController v4.0.0.0]

**ApiController v5.2.3.0**

[image: ApiController v5.2.3.0]

Comment: This is likely to do with them unifying the MVC Controller and WebAPI controller in the latest version.

Comment: Depends how you define "latest". This version still has separate base classes for MVC vs. API controllers. Don't let the v5 fool you, it isn't the vNext version (even though that's called ASP.NET 5). Yeah, not confusing at all.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the issue. Sadly, the documentation doesn't state that clearly!

Comment: If you want to be even further confused, the documentation you referenced was for `Web.ApiCore 2.2`. What you're using is actually `Web.ApiCore`. So the v4.x version of the package is actually v1.x of the product and the v5.x version of the nuget package is actually v2.x of the product.